# use with SHIMANO 105 FD-5504 Front Derailleur on crankset 26/36/48t

Tags: derailleur, crankset, front

Can I use a SHIMANO 105 FD-5504 Front Derailleur with Crankset 26/36/48t?
My Cogset Shimano HG-50, 11– 32t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking yes, presuming everything else about the chain, ring spacing, and shifter play nice. What you'll tend to find is the gap with the ring will be a little wider than ideal at the tail end of the cage,  since FD-5504 is contoured for a 52. Usually this effect won't be enough to keep it from working fine.